# data.table WHERE before BY

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following problem, which has probably a pretty simple solution:
When I use

```
library (data.table)
actions = data.table(User_id = c("Carl","Carl","Carl","Lisa","Moe"),
                     category = c(1,1,2,2,1),
                     value= c(10,20,30,40,50))

   User_id category value
1:    Carl        1    10
2:    Carl        1    20
3:    Carl        2    30
4:    Lisa        2    40
5:     Moe        1    50

actions[category==1,sum(value),by= User_id]
```

The problem is, that apparently it first sorts out the rows where category is 1 and then uses the by command. So what I get is:

```
   User_id V1
1:    Carl 30
2:     Moe 50
```

But what I want is:

```
   User_id V1
1:    Carl 30
2:    Lisa 0
3:     Moe 50
```

I am building a data.table just containing information about the users, so:

```
users = actions[,User_id,by= User_id]
users$value_one = actions[category==1,.(value_one =sum(value)),by= User_id]$value_one
```

which throws errors or includes wrong values, when there are some users that have no entry.

Comment: You could use `actions[,sum(ifelse(category == 1, value, 0)),by = User_id]`.

Comment: IIUC related to [FR #788](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is almost as succinct, and gets the job done.

```
actions[, .SD[category==1, sum(value)], by=User_id]
#    User_id V1
# 1:    Carl 30
# 2:    Lisa  0
# 3:     Moe 50

## Or, better yet, no need to muck around with .SD, (h.t. David Arenburg)
actions[, sum(value[category == 1]), by = User_id]
#    User_id V1
# 1:    Carl 30
# 2:    Lisa  0
# 3:     Moe 50
```

If the relative inefficiency of the above is a problem in your use case, here's a more efficient alternative:

```
res <- actions[, .(val=0), by=User_id]
res[actions[category==1, .(val=sum(value)), by=User_id], val:=i.val, on="User_id"]    
res
#    User_id val
# 1:    Carl  30
# 2:    Lisa   0
# 3:     Moe  50
```

Comment: Or just `actions[, sum(value[category == 1]), by = User_id]` without messing around with `.SD`. Though, although these approaches seem "*almost as succinct*" they are much less efficient than what OP was trying to do because you filtering by `category==1` *by each* `User_id` rather only once.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Agreed. I had similar misgivings, so just added a second, less succinct but more efficient option.

Comment: Another way to deal with including unused levels would be a merge like `actions[category==1][users, sum(value, na.rm=TRUE), on="User_id", by=.EACHI]`. Unfortunately, looks like `sum` doesn't trigger GForce optimization if na.rm is involved

Comment: A crude way to get gforce on (similar to your res thing): `actions[, rbind(.SD, data.table(User_id = unique(User_id), value = 0), fill=TRUE)][, sum(value), by=User_id]`

Comment: @Frank -- Yep, that's the other option that seemed good to me. Here's what I had: `rbind(actions[category==1, .(User_id, value)], actions[, .(value=0), by=User_id])[,sum(value),by=User_id]` , which differs only in that I do the `rbind()` once, appending a data.table of 0 values with one row for each unique user id.